# What's the difference in meaning of this two sentences?

Tags: meaning, past-tense

1. They would often visit friends in Europe.
2. They often visited friends in Europe.

Comment: It's best if you say what you understand, and what you want help with. For example, one sentence uses the past tense ("visited"). Do you have a question about how that changes the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: yeah, downvote me so I'll never know the difference. I used google translator and it translates them to the same sentence in my language

Comment: The meaning is very similar, that's why I asked. I don't downvote questions. The short answer might be, there really is no difference, it says that "some people visit Europe" more than once to see friends there.

Comment: @user8356 google translate says this two sentences mean the same but I'm not so sure. I never encounter a sentence built like the first one. I know that both of them relate to the past. But do they really mean the same?

Comment: @user8356 I'm confused because I thought 'would' is used to show someone's purposes

Comment: Yes, they really are very similar. It's different words for the same meaning. "I would often do this" is a phrase that means the same as "I often did this." -- I would often go to church" puts it in the past. "I often went to church" is really exactly the same. "I go to church" on the other hand, in present tense, means now...I haven't stopped going to church. But the other sentence could mean you don't go now.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it is interesting that using "would do" puts it in the past, the same as "did." It's true that one use of "Would" is for "conditional" sentences ("I would go if I wasn't working"). But "would often do something" is about the past, and suggests that you no longer do it, or not as often anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is almost the same.

*Would visit* gives a strong sense of "it was their habit", while *visited* does not have that connotation; but with *often*, there is really no difference.

This is a specific meaning of *would*: habit in the past; it is a bit literary. In speech, people are more likely to say *used to visit*.

I'm going to disagree with Ram Pillai: I don't think there is a parallel in the current language between *visit/will visit* and *visited/would visit* (though I don't doubt that historically that is the origin of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

//They would often visit friends in Europe.
They often visited friends in Europe.//

Compare these two:

They said, "We will often visit friends in Europe."
They said that they would often visit friends in Europe. (This cannot be replaced by 'They often visited friends in Europe.)

They said, "We often visit friends in Europe."
They said that they often visited friends in Europe. (This cannot be replaced with 'They would often visit friends in Europe.)

Meaning-wise there is not much a difference. Both are habitual actions of the past.